# MySQL Query Select Name FROM Foreign Key That From Same Table

Tags: mysql

So i have a table named employee that contains a foreign key from the same table `Employee`
[image: employee]

I want to select `employee.name` and the `reportsTo's.name`, the question is,

how i get the reportsTo's name if the foreign key is from the same table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 table copies:

```
SELECT t1.firstName, t1.lastName, t2.firstName, t2.lastName
FROM employee t1
LEFT JOIN employee t2 ON t1.reportsTo = t2.employeeNumber
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to use `INEER JOIN` to display the common values of each table.

**SQL INNER JOIN Keyword**

> *The `INNER JOIN` keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.* [1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

**INNER JOIN DIAGRAM**
[image: inner join]

**Syntax**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

**Code**

```
SELECT employees.firstName, employees.lastName, reportsTo.firstName, reportsTo.lastName 
FROM employees 
INNER JOIN reportsTo
ON employees.employeeNumber = reportsTo.employeeNumber 
ORDER BY (employees.firstname, employees.lastname);
```